# duplicate data being return with varied # of results in cross join

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I created a database for a clothing brand. The products consists of 3 tables: products, product_photos, inventory.

The issue I'm having pertains to the amount of results in the product_photos, inventory tables that are returned. So say there should be 4 results in the inventory table (ex. size: s, m, l, xl AND quantity: 20, 20, 20, 20) and 1 result in the product_photos table (ex. photos: url). With my current query the product_photos data is duplicated 4 times (ex. photos: url, url, url, url).

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
  products.id, 
  products.type, 
  products.collection, 
  products.title, 
  products.price, 
  products.thumbnail, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(product_photos.id) AS photoId, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(product_photos.photo) AS photos, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(inventory.size) AS size,                                  
  GROUP_CONCAT(inventory.quantity) as quantity 
FROM `products` 
RIGHT JOIN 
`product_photos` ON products.id = product_photos.product_id 
RIGHT JOIN `inventory` ON products.id = inventory.product_id 
WHERE
products.id = ?
GROUP BY
products.id
```

I have played around with some things such as changing the right's to inner join's and left join's but right join seems to be the technical choice for what I'm trying to do.

Here is some sample data:

```
product:
 id: 1

product_photo:
 id: 1,
 product_id: 1,
 photo: url

inventory:
 id: 1,
 product_id: 1,
 size: s,
 quantity: 20

 id: 2,
 product_id: 1,
 size: l,
 quantity: 14
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and your expected output from them.

Comment: ... without a proper data sample  and the expected  result as tabular text  your question is not clear ..

Comment: It's unusual to see right joins - not wrong necessarily but I think left joins are more appropriate in this case

Comment: using left joins doesn't change my result. I'm sure your right though and I had the A and B tables backwards in my mind. Also product_id isn't unique in inventory because there's multiple rows. I'll edit my post with sample data right now

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry thanks that's a good resource, I'll definitely use some of those tips for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the many results is that both the `product_photos` as and the `inventory` table can have multiple records for the same `product_id` and so all pairwise combinations of records from both tables will be iterated (Cartesian product).

You can solve this by first selecting all records from both these tables with a `union` and then join that *result* with the `products` table:

```
SELECT      products.id, 
            products.type, 
            products.collection, 
            products.title, 
            products.price, 
            products.thumbnail,
            GROUP_CONCAT(photoId) AS photoId,
            GROUP_CONCAT(photos) AS photos,
            GROUP_CONCAT(size) AS size,                                  
            GROUP_CONCAT(quantity) as quantity 
FROM        products
LEFT JOIN   (
                SELECT  product_id, 
                        id AS photoId, 
                        photo AS photos,
                        null AS size,
                        null AS quantity
                FROM    product_photos
                UNION
                SELECT  product_id,
                        null,
                        null,
                        size,                                  
                        quantity 
                FROM    inventory 
            ) combi
         ON products.product_id = combi.product_id
WHERE       products.id = ?
GROUP BY    products.id
```

Comment: Interesting I had never heard of cross join/cartesian product before your answer. Thanks for clarifying it makes much more sense now

Answer (score 0):

This problem would normally be handled by aggregating along each dimension independently:

```
SELECT p.*
       pp.photoIds, pp.photos,
       i.sizes, i.quantitys
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT pp.product_id,
             GROUP_CONCAT(pp.id) AS photoIds, 
             GROUP_CONCAT(pp.photo) AS photos 
      FROM product_photos pp
      GROUP BY pp.product_id
     ) pp
     ON p.id = pp.product_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT i.product_id,
             GROUP_CONCAT(i.size) AS sizes,                                  
             GROUP_CONCAT(i.quantity) as quantitys
      FROM inventory i
      GROUP BY i.product_id
     ) i
     ON p.id = i.product_id 
WHERE p.id = ?;
```

Notes:

- You want `LEFT JOIN` from the `products` table, not `RIGHT JOIN`.  Presumably, you want information about a product if it is available, not only if it has inventory.
- You should include an `ORDER BY` so the `GROUP_CONCAT()` values *are guaranteed* to be in the same order.  That is, the first `id` matches the first image, for instance.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

The above should be more efficient (and simpler to code and follow0 than using `UNION` -- or `UNION ALL`).  That is, two aggregations on "n" rows should be more efficient than one aggregation on "2 * n" rows.  In more sophisticated databases, this formulation also gives the optimizer more information.

Because you only want this for one product, it is actually more efficient to filter *before* the aggregation:

```
SELECT p.*
       pp.photoIds, pp.photos,
       i.sizes, i.quantitys
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT pp.product_id,
             GROUP_CONCAT(pp.id) AS photoIds, 
             GROUP_CONCAT(pp.photo) AS photos 
      FROM product_photos pp
      WHERE pp.product_id = ?
      GROUP BY pp.product_id
     ) pp
     ON p.id = pp.product_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT i.product_id,
             GROUP_CONCAT(i.size) AS sizes,                                  
             GROUP_CONCAT(i.quantity) as quantitys
      FROM inventory i
      WHERE i.product_id = ?
      GROUP BY i.product_id
     ) i
     ON p.id = i.product_id 
WHERE p.id = ?;
```

In this case, you need to pass the parameter three times.